# updating image hasfile condition

Tags: laravel

Now i'm trying to update an image but in method update it keeps skip the `hasfile` condition

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

        $slider = Slider::find($id);

        $slider->header = $request->header;
        $slider->paragraph=$request->paragraph;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        return 'a';
        // $image=$request->file('image');
        // $filename=time(). '.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // $location=public_path('images/' . $filename);
        // Image::make($image)->save($location);

        // $oldFilename=$slider->image;

        // $slider->image=$filename;

        // File::delete(public_path('images/'. $oldFilename));

          }else{
            return 'whatever';
          }
}
```

and here's my view

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('slider.update',$slider->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {{ csrf_field() }}         

        {{method_field('PATCH')}}


              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title  back-change">
                       <h5>الغلاف </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="image-crop">
                                <img  src="{{asset('images/'.$slider->image)}}">
                             </div>
                          </div>



                          <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="btn-group">
                                <label title="Upload image file" for="inputImage" class="btn btn-primary">
                               <input type="file" name="image"  id="inputImage" class="hide">
                                Upload new image
                                </label>
                               </div>
                          </div>



                           <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                                   <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit"> حفظ التغيرات</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Why can I not get to the condition?

The form is okay and the name of the input is okay, but it still returns to `else`.

Comment: Maybe you are using the id `inputImage` somewhere else, try changing the id and see if it works.

Comment: And if you dd($request->all()) just before your if statement, just to see whats in your request?

Comment: it give me nothing ..